# Connection to MySQL in Visual Studio blocked

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debian

I currently have a MySQL installation running on a linux server which I've (until now) I only ever used on localhost. I'm now looking to use this database with an application I'm writing in C# and to do so I've just installed the MySQL Connector for .NET to connect to it externally in .NET.

When attempting to connect however, I am getting this error message:
[image: ERROR!]

I thought it wasn't setup correctly when it wouldn't find my database name list, however I can only think that this is down to the setup on the linux server.

It is not limited to local only connections so I cannot see what would be blocking this... could it be the firewall on my machine running the windows application? Let me know if anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening...

EDIT: This isn't a firewall issue AFAIK.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/

Comment: Thanks, there's no need for a downvote whoever did that though...

Comment: Wasn't me ;) -- I don't think I've ever down-voted anyone.  I hope that link helps I had a similar issue with an Oracle Express install not too long ago.  Out of the box, the DBs ship pretty tight (security-wise) lately.  This is good thing.

Comment: Thanks, yea I guess it is a good thing. One thing though, I've done the GRANT stuff mentioned in that link, restarted mysql and I'm still getting this error. I've even opened the port and still getting it... :(

Comment: Here is a bit better description, start at the "If the following error occurs when you try to connect from a host other than the one on which the MySQL server is running, it means that there is no row in the user table with a Host value that matches the client host" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.htmlsection.

Comment: Also, I don't see how this is off topic. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Comment: Got it working thanks. Can you post an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: No worries man after all you figured it out I just pointed you in the general direction.  Glad to hear it is sorted!  On to the next puzzle.. ;)

Comment: Do you not want the rep? It will go as unanswered otherwise! Thanks though!

Comment: You'll find the answer here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html